# How to animate hiding/showing of a QVBoxLayout widget

Tags: qt, animation, layout, pyqt, show-hide

I have this horizontal layout of a `QWidget` subclass using `QHBoxLayout`:
[image: Layout]

I would like the top widget to hide/show in sliding animation. I have read [this article](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8955), and I know that I have to use `QPropertyAnimation`. Frankly, not a good Google result come up.

Any suggestion for code example or maybe link to an article?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `maximumHeight` property of the top widget in an animation.

For hiding the top widget :

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->topWidget, "maximumHeight");
animation->setDuration(1000);
animation->setStartValue(500);
animation->setEndValue(0);

animation->start();
```

for showing the top widget :

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->topWidget, "maximumHeight");
animation->setDuration(1000);
animation->setStartValue(0);
animation->setEndValue(500);

animation->start();
```

Comment: Hm... I think I understand now how the QPropertyAnimation works.. Will check this tomorrow morning and report it here. But I think it's save to mark this as answered

Comment: It's worth noting the above code is c++ code, not Python code (the question is tagged pyqt)