# Animating a QVBoxLayout when using stretch factors/when the final size is unknown

Tags: qt, animation

This post is closely related to [this question about animating a QVBoxLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106177/how-to-animate-hiding-showing-of-a-qvboxlayout-widget), which got me half-way back when I found it.

I have a QVBoxLayout containing a few widgets. The last of them is only visible in certain situations, so I want to animate it when it appears and disappears.
I'm currently using `QPropertyAnimation` to animate the `maximumHeight` property of the widget I want to show and hide. However, the issue here is that I don't know what size the widget should be: the `QVBoxLayout` decides that, based on the parent window size and stretch factors.
Therefore, I don't know what values I should give to `QPropertyAnimation::setStartValue` and `setEndValue`, for the show animation (when hiding, it should work to simply use the current height).

It sort-of works to simply give a very excessive value (such as 2000 px, when you expect it to rarely be larger than 400), since we're animating the *maximum* height, but that has issues. Namely, the `finished` signal is emitted after the *full* animation duration, even if the animation stopped (visually) long ago, as the widget reached its allotted size.
When hiding, the issue is instead that the animation is delayed: from 2000 px to the current `height()`, nothing happens; after that, it collapses quickly.

I then considered animating the stretch factors instead, but couldn't find a way to, since they're not exposed as properties.
As a last resort, it might be possible to subclass the layout and create a property that adjusts the stretch factor of the last two items, but that feels like a huge hack in several ways.

How can I animate this in a nice way?

Just in case somebody's going to ask for a code example, I wrote a simple test application. If you weren't going to ask, you can probably skip looking through it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QTextEdit *topTextEdit = nullptr;
QTextEdit *bottomTextEdit = nullptr;

void toggleButtonClicked() {
    QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(bottomTextEdit, 
                                                      "maximumHeight");
    anim->setDuration(1200);

    if (bottomTextEdit->isVisible()) {
        anim->setStartValue(1000);
        anim->setEndValue(0);
        QObject::connect(anim, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, [] {
            bottomTextEdit->hide();
            topTextEdit->append("Animation finished");
        });
    }
    else {
        bottomTextEdit->show();
        anim->setStartValue(0);
        anim->setEndValue(1000);
        QObject::connect(anim, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, [] {
            topTextEdit->append("Animation finished");
        });
    }

    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    topTextEdit->append("Animation started");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    topTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    bottomTextEdit = new QTextEdit;

    QPushButton *toggleButton = new QPushButton("Toggle");
    QObject::connect(toggleButton, &QPushButton::released,
                     &toggleButtonClicked);

    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;
    vbox->addWidget(toggleButton);
    vbox->addWidget(topTextEdit, 10);
    vbox->addWidget(bottomTextEdit, 6);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(vbox);

    bottomTextEdit->setMaximumHeight(0);
    bottomTextEdit->hide();
    widget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the subclassing route, since I couldn't think of anything else, and this question didn't see a lot of activity.

The subclass (*must be in a header file* or you'll get undefined reference to vtable errors):

```
class EVBoxLayout : public QVBoxLayout {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int lastStretch READ lastStretch WRITE setLastStretch)

public:
    EVBoxLayout() {}
    int lastStretch() const { return this->stretch(this->count() - 1); }
    void setLastStretch(int newStretch) {
        this->setStretch(this->count() - 1, newStretch);
    }
};
```

After implementing that, replace the `QVBoxLayout` with an `EVBoxLayout`, and create the animation using

```
QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(vbox, "lastStretch");
```

There are several points to consider for this to work:

- For the animation to be smooth, you should probably use very large stretch factors; since they are integers, an animation from e.g. 1 to 5 will be very choppy. I went with a 1000:600 ratio, so my animation is from 1 to 600 for the bottom widget, which I want to be the smaller one.
- Make sure to set the minimum height of the widget to 1 (not 0!), or the animation may begin part-way.
- Make sure to animate the stretch factor *from 1*, not from 0, or there will be a flicker when the animation begins.

The solution feels hacky, but it looks and works great in practice.
For completeness, here's the full test program, updated to use this fix:

main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QVBoxLayout>

class EVBoxLayout : public QVBoxLayout {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int lastStretch READ lastStretch WRITE setLastStretch)

public:
    int lastStretch() const { return this->stretch(this->count() - 1); }
    void setLastStretch(int newStretch) { this->setStretch(this->count() - 1, newStretch); }
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QTextEdit *topTextEdit = nullptr;
QTextEdit *bottomTextEdit = nullptr;   
EVBoxLayout *vbox = nullptr;

void toggleButtonClicked() {
    QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(vbox, "lastStretch");
    anim->setDuration(250);

    // Without this, the scrollbar may appear (and then disappear again)
    // during animation.
    bottomTextEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    if (bottomTextEdit->isVisible()) {
        anim->setStartValue(600);
        anim->setEndValue(1);
        QObject::connect(anim, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, [] {
            bottomTextEdit->hide();
            topTextEdit->append("Animation finished");
            bottomTextEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
        });
    }
    else {
        bottomTextEdit->show();
        anim->setStartValue(1);
        anim->setEndValue(600);
        QObject::connect(anim, &QPropertyAnimation::finished, [] {
            topTextEdit->append("Animation finished");
            bottomTextEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
        });
    }

    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    topTextEdit->append("Animation started");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    topTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    bottomTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    bottomTextEdit->setMinimumHeight(1);

    QPushButton *toggleButton = new QPushButton("Toggle");
    QObject::connect(toggleButton, &QPushButton::released,
                     &toggleButtonClicked);

    vbox = new EVBoxLayout;
    vbox->addWidget(toggleButton);
    vbox->addWidget(topTextEdit, 1000);
    vbox->addWidget(bottomTextEdit, 1);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widget->setLayout(vbox);

    bottomTextEdit->hide();
    widget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I'll wait another day or so to accept this as an answer, in case someone comes along with something less hacky (such as a way to calculate the exact final size from the stretch factors).